# What does it mean when there is a dash between two numbers in C `define`?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 96-48
```

I printed `BUFF_SIZE` in x64 and it printed 48 but I'm not sure what the meaning of `96-48` actually is.

Comment: It's just ordinary subtraction.

Comment: Hint: Try with `1+1`.

Comment: Just like if you wrote `a = b-c;` -- it subtracts the second number from the first one.

Comment: And it should be in parentheses: `#define BUFF_SIZE (96-48)` Otherwise, a calculation like `2*BUFF_SIZE` won't work correctly.

Comment: Macros just do simple text substitution. So if you write `a = BUFF_SIZE;` it's the same as writing `a = 96-48;`

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! I thought there is some rare range specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every macro in C and C++ are literal values, put into place by the compiler. So 96-48 means literally 96 minus 48, that is equal to 48.

When you have the snippet:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2   
3 #define BUFF_SIZE 96-48
4  
5 int main(void) {
6     printf("%d\n", BUFF_SIZE);
7     return 0;
8 }
```

The compiler literally puts `printf("%d\n", 96-48);` in your code.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's actually before compile time.  In fact, it's (I believe) before any lexical/syntactic analysis is performed on the source.  It's also not the compiler but the preprocessor doing the work.

Comment: You're right! I believe the task is done by the pre-processor, right? Good point. I've edited the answer with a subtle, but relevant detail. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielWalker: There is lexical and syntactic analysis. Macro replacement operates on preprocessing tokens, not plain text. A preprocessing token is one of a header name, an identifier, a preprocessing number, a character constant, a string literal, a punctuator, or a white-space character. These all have particular forms that must be parsed. The preprocessor also has to do some grammatical parsing, so that the arguments to the macro `foo` in `foo((3, 4), 5)` are not separated at the first comma and do not end at the first `)`.

Comment: For that reason, this answer is wrong to say “The compiler literally puts `printf("%d\n", 96-48);` in your code.” The compiler likely has some internal representation, so the result of the macro replacement is a representation of the separate tokens `printf`, `"%d\n"`, `,`, white space, `96`, `-`, `)`, and `;`. From time to time, we see other questions on Stack Overflow where somebody has expected a literal text replacement, and it does not work because macro replacement works with parsed tokens, not text.

Comment: Yeah, that reminds me the Javascript spec. The beginning of the document describes the interpreter behavior and it's very similar with what you're saying. But I believe that process is after the macro substitution. First it replaces the literal value, then, of course, it must be processed to evaluation.

Comment: Here's what K&R says about the preprocessor, by the way: - "A preprocessing step performs macro substitution on program text, inclusion of other source files, and conditional compilation."

Comment: Don't mention it! I appreciate your info too! Just for further curiosity, I've put the K&R word to the test, and generated the preprocessor output of the answer's snippet. `gcc -E test.c | grep -P ^\\s+printf` prints ` printf("%d\n", 96-48);` It's interesting to see the theory in practice.

Comment: @Daniel Walker, You're confusing compiling and parsing. It's done by the compiler these days, but before *parsing*.  It's done theoretically before lexing too, but it wouldn't surprise me if the line between the two stages is blurry/non-existant.

Comment: Sorry I downvoted this answer because a macro isn't literal value but literal code. "So 96-48 means literally 96 minus 48, that is equal to 48." isn't true. Please do not confuse values with tokens. Preprocessor doesn't do values.